# What does the 'put' keyword do in Python

Tags: python

I saw the following code

```
 q.put(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
```

and can't figure out what 'put' does. Yes, I searched google and could not find any information on it, obviously the docs does not yield a result since I don't know what i'm looking for.

Comment: Is `q` a queue? In this case read [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.put).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, when I see a variable called `q` I assume that it is a `Queue` object, which is used in multithreading/multiprocessing. `put` is essentially the queue equivalent of the `append` method of lists.

If `q` is declared in a line like this:

```
import Queue
...
q = Queue.Queue()
```

or like this

```
from Queue import Queue
...
q = Queue()
```

then it's just adding the result of the `read` operation to the queue. If that's not enough to help you understand the example that you're looking at, then I'd suggest you go look up some examples of `Queue`s in python to get a feel for how they work.

Answer (score 9):

`put` is *not* a keyword. It is a method on the `q` object.

Without knowledge of what `q` *is*, there isn't much more that can be said.

Some examples of possibilities:

- [`requests.put()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.put) will send a PUT HTTP request to a named URL.
- [`Queue.put()`](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.put) will add an item to a multi-threading queue.

You'll need to take a good look at the source code and see what `q` is bound to, then look up documentation for that object.